# Make Variables from Parent Shell Script

Tags: makefile

In a makefile I'm reading, there are many references to a variable, `projdir`, defined and exported in the shell script that calls make; there are many instances of `$(projdir)` in the makefile.

From the make manual at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference, there are only two types of variables: recursively expanded variables and simply expanded variables. It seems `projdir` is neither one.

Question 1: Since the makefile works, it must be true that makefiles can access shell variables defined in the parent shell environment. Why is this not documented (or perhaps I did not find the correct documentation)?

Question 2: Unrelated to question 1, I see in Section 6.2 the line `all:;echo $(foo)`. Why is the semicolon `;` needed here?

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment: _Every environment variable that make sees when it starts up is transformed into a make variable with the same name and value._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1. Environment variables automatically become `make` variables. This is explained in [section 6.10](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment):

> Variables in make can come from the environment in which make is run. Every environment variable that make sees when it starts up is transformed into a make variable with the same name and value.

Question 2: Putting a semicolon after a rule name and optional prerequisites allows you to start the recipe on the same line. This is explained in [section 4.2](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax):

> The first recipe line may appear on the line after the prerequisites, with a tab character, or may appear on the same line, with a semicolon.

They used this syntax in the example in 6.2 for brevity, so they could show the whole rule inline in the sentence; I think it's rarely used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

From the `make` [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment):

> Variables in `make` can come from the environment in which `make` is run. Every environment variable that `make` sees when it starts up is transformed into a make variable with the same name and value.

As to your second question:

> Why is the semicolon `;` needed here?

Without the semicolon the right-hand side of `:` would specify the list of dependencies. The semicolon terminates that (empty) list.

Answer (score 1):

Variables have *both* a `flavor` and an `origin`.

Expansion type is a `flavor`.

make contains a [`flavor` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavor-Function) which can be used to find the type of variable in question. It will return one of `undefined`, `recursive` or `simple`.

Variables also have an `origin` which is where their value has come from. What you are seeing here is one of those possible origins.

The [`origin` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Origin-Function) will tell you the origin of a variable.

There are seven possible origins: `undefined`, `default`, `environment`, `environment override`, `file`, `command line`, `override` and `automatic`.

So your `projdir` variable has a `flavor` of `simple` and an `origin` of `environment`.